# Cannot compile `solana-program` crate with new `sqlx` versions

Tags: solana-program, rust, cargo, rustc

For some reason when trying to compile a project having both `sqlx` and `solana-program` I get an error on package version mismatches, which is strange, because those should come from different crates and are unreleated?
Is there anything I can do to use newer `sqlx` version, or am I stuck with `0.6.3`?

Here are the exerts:

```
solana-program = "1.18.2"
sqlx = { version = "0.7.3", features = ["postgres", "runtime-tokio-rustls", "time", "macros", "bigdecimal"] }
```

```
error: failed to select a version for `zeroize`.
    ... required by package `rsa v0.9.0`
    ... which satisfies dependency `rsa = "^0.9"` of package `sqlx-mysql v0.7.3`
    ... which satisfies dependency `sqlx-mysql = "=0.7.3"` of package `sqlx v0.7.3`
    ... which satisfies dependency `sqlx = "^0.7.3"` of package `solana-program-pain v0.1.0 (/home/sheep/LinksDevices/Space/home/_Work/solana-program-pain)`
versions that meet the requirements `^1.5` are: 1.7.0, 1.6.0, 1.5.7, 1.5.6, 1.5.5, 1.5.4, 1.5.3

all possible versions conflict with previously selected packages.

  previously selected package `zeroize v1.0.0`
    ... which satisfies dependency `zeroize = ">=1, <1.4"` of package `curve25519-dalek v3.2.1`
    ... which satisfies dependency `curve25519-dalek = "^3.2.1"` of package `solana-program v1.18.2`
    ... which satisfies dependency `solana-program = "^1.18.2"` of package `solana-program-pain v0.1.0 (/home/sheep/LinksDevices/Space/home/_Work/solana-program-pain)`

failed to select a version for `zeroize` which could resolve this co
```

Answer (score 1):

It's a bit annoying, but it's possible to fix this if you patch a few crates in your Cargo.toml. There's a PR out to do that in the Solana monorepo at https://github.com/solana-labs/solana/pull/33853. In your case, you'll need:

```
[patch.crates-io.aes-gcm-siv]
git = "https://github.com/RustCrypto/AEADs"
rev = "6105d7a5591aefa646a95d12b5e8d3f55a9214ef"

[patch.crates-io.curve25519-dalek]
git = "https://github.com/solana-labs/curve25519-dalek.git"
rev = "c14774464c4d38de553c6ef2f48a10982c1b4801"
```